# How do I remove -Werror from autotools-generated makefiles?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake, suppress-warnings, autogen

I am compiling a large library which uses the autotools build process.  There are many makefiles.  Each of them are getting `CFLAGS = .... -Werror`.

When I attempt to compile there are some minor warnings which kill the build on my setup.

I would like to try building despite the warnings so I need to take the -`Werror` out of all the makefiles.  Is there a way to prevent autotools from putting in `-Werror` in all these makefiles?

Comment: Check `configure.ac` - it might contain something like `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Werror])`. Do not edit the Makefile/s as those are generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I poked around in configure.ac and found this:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([werror],
  AS_HELP_STRING([--disable-werror], [Do not treat warnings as errors]),
  [gcc_werror=$enableval], [gcc_werror=$gcc_warnings])
```

So I ran configure like this:

```
./configure --disable-werror
```

It worked like a charm.  No more `-Werror` flags in my makefile.  Thanks for your comment Till!

Comment: Note for anyone who ended up here that this is highly project dependent. Some projects use "--disable-werror" others use "--disable-Werror" and some projects may not offer a flag to modify builds in this manner. Take a look through the project's 'configure.ac' file and './configure --help' output to see if such flags are offered.

Answer (score 1):

My sed way, after Makefile created

```
find . -name Makefile -exec sed -i s'/-Werror//g' {} \;
```

In Mac replace `sed` with `gsed`

Answer (score 0):

For autotools based project you may need to pass:

```
./autogen.sh --disable-Werror
```

Observe the upper-case `W` in `Werror`.

Comment: Note for anyone who ended up here that this is highly project dependent. Some projects use "--disable-werror" others use "--disable-Werror" and some projects may not offer a flag to modify builds in this manner. Take a look through the project's 'configure.ac' file and './configure --help' output to see if such flags are offered.